# Adjusting Output Size of Auxiliary Matrix in Python

Tags: python, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

After hidden layer activation, I want to create an auxiliary matrix to better capture the temporal aspect of the data in the below code snippet. The current shape of the return variable is `[out_channels, out_channels]` but I want the returned shape to be `[input_channels, out_channels]`. Which part of the code should be modified to achieve the desired output while keeping the idea/logic as it is?

```
def my_fun( self, H: torch.FloatTensor,) -> torch.FloatTensor:
    
    self.input_channels = 4
    self.out_channels = 16
    self.forgettingFactor = 0.92
    self.lamb = 0.01
    self.M = torch.inverse(self.lamb*torch.eye(self.out_channels))
    HH = self.calculateHiddenLayerActivation(H) # [4,16]
    Ht = HH.t() # [16 , 4]
    ###### Computation of auxiliary matrix 
    
    initial_product = torch.mm((1 / self.forgettingFactor) * self.M, Ht) # [16, 4]
    intermediate_matrix = torch.mm(HH, initial_product )   # [4, 4]
    sum_inside_pseudoinverse = torch.eye(self.input_channels) + intermediate_matrix # [4, 4]

    pseudoinverse_sum = torch.pinverse(sum_inside_pseudoinverse) # [4, 4]
    product_inside_expression = torch.mm(HH, (1/self.forgettingFactor) * self.M) #  [4, 16]              
    dot_product_pseudo = torch.mm( pseudoinverse_sum  , product_inside_expression) # [4, 16]   
    dot_product_with_hidden_matrix = torch.mm(Ht, dot_product_pseudo ) # [16, 16]

    res = (1/self.forgettingFactor) * self.M - torch.mm((1/self.forgettingFactor) * self.M, dot_product_with_hidden_matrix  ) # [16,16]        

    return res
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current logic results in a shape of `[out_channels, out_channels]` due to the matrix multiplication operations involved.

The shape of the resulting matrix from a matrix multiplication depends on the shapes of the matrices involved. Specifically, if you multiply a matrix A of shape `[m, n]` with a matrix B of shape `[n, p]`, the resulting matrix C will have a shape `[m, p]` (as documented in [`torch.mm()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mm.html)).

```py
initial_product = torch.mm((1 / self.forgettingFactor) * self.M, Ht) # [16, 4]
```

`self.M` is `[out_channels, out_channels]`, and `Ht` is `[out_channels, input_channels]`.
The result `initial_product` is `[out_channels, input_channels]`.

```py
intermediate_matrix = torch.mm(HH, initial_product) # [4, 4]
```

`HH` is `[input_channels, out_channels]`, and `initial_product` is `[out_channels, input_channels]`.
The result `intermediate_matrix` is `[input_channels, input_channels]`.

```py
dot_product_with_hidden_matrix = torch.mm(Ht, dot_product_pseudo) # [16, 16]
```

`Ht` is `[out_channels, input_channels]`, and `dot_product_pseudo` is `[input_channels, out_channels]`.
The result `dot_product_with_hidden_matrix` is `[out_channels, out_channels]`.

```py
res = (1/self.forgettingFactor) * self.M - torch.mm((1/self.forgettingFactor) * self.M, dot_product_with_hidden_matrix) # [16,16]
```

The subtraction is between two matrices of shape `[out_channels, out_channels]`.
The final `res` is therefore also `[out_channels, out_channels]`.

So to get a shape of `[input_channels, out_channels]` for the final output, you will need to adjust the matrix multiplication steps in your code, making sure the final matrix operations involve matrices with dimensions that, when multiplied, result in the shape `[input_channels, out_channels]`.

```py
def my_fun(self, H: torch.FloatTensor) -> torch.FloatTensor:
    # [Previous code remains the same]

    # Adjusted computation
    initial_product = torch.mm((1 / self.forgettingFactor) * self.M, Ht) # [16, 4]
    intermediate_matrix = torch.mm(HH, initial_product) # [4, 4]
    sum_inside_pseudoinverse = torch.eye(self.input_channels) + intermediate_matrix # [4, 4]

    pseudoinverse_sum = torch.pinverse(sum_inside_pseudoinverse) # [4, 4]
    product_inside_expression = torch.mm(HH, (1/self.forgettingFactor) * self.M) # [4, 16]

    # Modified part
    res = torch.mm(pseudoinverse_sum, product_inside_expression) # [4, 16]

    return res
```

- `pseudoinverse_sum` has a shape of `[input_channels, input_channels]` (i.e., `[4, 4]`).
- `product_inside_expression` remains `[input_channels, out_channels]` (i.e., `[4, 16]`).
- The final result `res` is obtained by multiplying `pseudoinverse_sum` and `product_inside_expression`, resulting in a shape of `[input_channels, out_channels]` (i.e., `[4, 16]`).

You would remove the last few steps that were leading to an `[out_channels, out_channels]` shape, to directly calculate `res` as the product of `pseudoinverse_sum` and `product_inside_expression`.

---

> If I ignore the remaining steps my model performs very poorly. These steps are necessary to capture the temporal dependencies inside the data.

OK, your last steps were:

```py
dot_product_pseudo = torch.mm(pseudoinverse_sum, product_inside_expression) # [4, 16]
dot_product_with_hidden_matrix = torch.mm(Ht, dot_product_pseudo) # [16, 16]
res = (1/self.forgettingFactor) * self.M - torch.mm((1/self.forgettingFactor) * self.M, dot_product_with_hidden_matrix) # [16, 16]
```

You could modify them with:

```py
dot_product_pseudo = torch.mm(pseudoinverse_sum, product_inside_expression) # [4, 16]
# Introduce a new matrix to adjust the dimension
adjustment_matrix = torch.randn(self.out_channels, self.input_channels) # [16, 4]
adjusted_dot_product = torch.mm(adjustment_matrix, dot_product_pseudo) # [16, 16]
res = (1/self.forgettingFactor) * self.M - torch.mm((1/self.forgettingFactor) * self.M, adjusted_dot_product) # [16, 16]

# Final adjustment to get the desired shape
final_res = torch.mm(HH, res) # [4, 16]
```

`adjustment_matrix` is added to transform `dot_product_pseudo` into a shape that can be used in the final `res` calculation without losing the existing logic.
`adjusted_dot_product` makes sure the temporal dependency capturing steps are preserved.
And `final_res` is computed by multiplying `HH` and `res` to get the desired shape of `[input_channels, out_channels]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I ignore the remaining steps my model performs very poorly. These steps are necessary to capture the temporal dependencies inside the data.

Comment: @Asif OK, good point. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: in the last line, I think it would be HH instead of HH.t().

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired output form [input_channels, out_channels] by transposing `Ht` before performing matrix multiplication with `dot_product_pseudo`. Here is the updated code:

```py
dot_product_with_hidden_matrix = torch.mm(dot_product_pseudo, Ht.t())
```

Comment: The shape of dot_product_pseudo  is [input_channels, out_channels] and the same is of Ht.t(). Ht.t() is equal to HH. Therefore this operation can not be performed.